# how to make a directory as a package

Tags: python

I have 2 python  files  `a` and `b` that are mutually dependent which raises a circular import error anytime when I import one from the other. I saw this post online which talks about creating a third file `__init.py__` in the same directory as `a` and `b` and putting all the imports in the third file, hence the folder containing these 3 files becomes a `package`, correct? So in this case, the package can be imported in both `a` and `b` and submodules can be accessed however when I import the `package` in `a` and `b`, it gives an error that `package is not defined`. I am not sure, if I am creating the package correctly. Below is my code demonstration.

```
/code
 /package    # this becomes a package, correct?
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

In `__init__.py`

```
from . import a
from . import b
```

In `a.py`

```
import package   # this throws "package is not defined" error
package.b.some_variable
```

In `b.py`

```
import package   # this also throws "package is not defined" error
package.a.some_variable
```

Comment: *"mutually dependent"* — Well, there's the fundamental problem. That just doesn't work. At least not at the top level. If you `import` something in a function, then there's a chance to resolve that circular dependency. If if they're circularly dependent at the top level, it simply *can't* be resolved.

Comment: You did call it `__init__.py` right? Not `__init.py__` ...

Comment: @Lecdi, yes that's a typo. I have corrected it in my post.

Comment: You should give a minimal example of what you really want to do. Python import machinery can allow declarations in either file to be used from the other one provided they can be loaded one after the other one. But you cannot import the top level package from a file of the package.

Comment: i would just say its a bad design. change the project structure, create utilities and common framework codes to overcome cyclic dependencies.